# How can I fix this Verilog syntax assign error?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

## The problem

I'm creating a circuit for a project. In this piece of code, I want to save the game choice of the `manche` winner.
I choose the game choice after I have controlled the actual winner.
This is the code:

```
always @(manche) begin : DATAPATH
        last_winner <= manche;
        case (manche)
          2'b00, 2'b11:
                  game_choice <= 2'b00;
            2'b01:
                count1 <= count1 + 1;
            game_choice <= first;
            2'b10:
                count2 <= count2 + 1;
            game_choice <= first;
        endcase
    end
```

The variables in this piece of code are:

- `last_winner`: a register that stores the last winner, taken from the actual output `manche`
- `game_choice`: the winner choice
- `first` and `second`: the choices of the players
- `count1` and `count2`: the players counters

Every time I run this code, I get these errors:

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) design.sv(187): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ':'.
** Error: (vlog-13069) design.sv(191): near "2": syntax error, unexpected INTEGER NUMBER.
```

## Expected

I tried to split this code in multiple `always` and it works, but I want to use just one `always`.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax errors can be fixed by using `begin/end` keywords around each pair of statements within each `case` item:

```
   always @(manche) begin : DATAPATH
            last_winner <= manche;
            case (manche)
                2'b00, 2'b11: begin // "begin/end" is optional here
                      game_choice <= 2'b00;
                end
                2'b01: begin
                    count1 <= count1 + 1;
                    game_choice <= first;
                end
                2'b10: begin
                    count2 <= count2 + 1;
                    game_choice <= first;
                end
            endcase
    end
```

The indentation of your code is unusual and misleading.

Although this may fix your syntax errors, there are other issues with this code that could cause problems for synthesis.

> I want to use just one `always`

This is a common misconception for people new to Verilog.  There is no need to try to cram all your code into a single `always` block.  In fact, it is often much better to separate code into multiple blocks.